# keepalived - service not available on the 'passive' host

Tags: ip, failover, keepalived

I've got ip failover configured on two hosts for a mysql (percona) cluster with keepalived;  the failover works as expected, but I cannot access the service from the host that is passive or in 'backup' state. I'll try to explain better. Both HOST1 and HOST2 share a virtual IP, say 1.2.3.4 that is assigned correctly by keepalived to one of them depending on their status (I'm using the 1.1.19 version with the unicast patch).

Say that at some point, 1.2.3.4 is assigned to HOST2. In this scenario, I can access the mysql cluster with

```
mysql -ur...-p 1.2.3.4
```

from any server in the nerwork, BUT HOST1. I can access it from HOST2 though.
If things change and the IP 1.2.3.4 is assigned again to HOST1, I can then access the cluster from HOST1, but not HOST2.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance
Vito

Comment: When switching the mysql service to HOST2, one thing you could try is to verify the arp table on HOST1 by running, assuming Linux, `arp -anv`. You should get the mac address of HOST2 for `1.2.3.4`. If not, then you could try flushing the arp cache